# qt permanently display delegate in view

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtableview, qtreeview, qabstractitemview

How do you use `QStyledItemDelegate` / `QItemDelegate` to permanently display a complex widget, i.e. to handle the `Qt.DisplayRole`, not just `Qt.EditRole`?

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) eludes to using paint()... but that's just way to complex! Let's take for example rendering a `QTreeView` or `QTableVeiw` inside of a `QTableView` cell.

There is `QAbstractItemView.setIndexWidget()`, but that is a bad idea as it only used to display static content (and whats the fun in static models?).

### Note

I found part of the answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615997/pyqt-how-to-set-qcombobox-in-a-table-view-using-qitemdelegate/17617147#17617147), but it was only a small subset of the answer, so I thought it warranted a new post with proper question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to use `QAbstractItemView.openPersistentEditor()` to always keep the cell in edit mode.

## Some additional key elements

1. The `Qt.EditRole` flag will need to be provided for the cells which use delegates.
2. `QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHintChanged.emit(index)` needs to be called anytime the size of the editor widget has changed.
3. Implementing `QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint()` can be tricky and tedious (or you can do `index.internalPointer().editor_widget.sizeHint()` assuming you saved a reference of the editor to the internal pointer during `QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor()`

   - here is a good post on how to determine sizes: [What are the mechanics of the default delegate for item views in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990029/what-are-the-mechanics-of-the-default-delegate-for-item-views-in-qt)

## Caution

It should be mentioned that opening editors is costly, so if you have thousands of indexes and they are all loaded at once, it can take a while. There are many ways to mitigate this issue:

1. Load the model incrementally using a thread
2. Use Qt's `fetchMore()` mechanism
3. call `openPersistentEditor` incrementally (using a timer, or as they come into view for the first time)
4. call `openPersistentEditor` when the parent is expanded and `closePersistentEditor` when the parent is collapsed, and possibly restrict the use of expand-all on nodes with many children.